# Bonjour Timeout

Tags: timeout, bonjour, zeroconf

When I close the lid of a notebook and put it into sleep it seems the registered bonjour services from that notebook in the network do not disappear anymore on other machines. Does Bonjour has a timeout I can set somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Bonjour's "Frequently Asked Questions" page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/faq.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008762-SW1):

> **When I disconnect a device from a network, does it remain visible?**
>
> Yes, for a while. Eventually, the DNS record reaches its time-to-live
>   interval and disappears. As an app developer, if you connect to a host
>   using Bonjour and the connection fails, you can ask the Bonjour to
>   reconfirm the record. This process is described further in
>   NSNetServices and CFNetServices Programming Guide.

Comment: DNSServiceReconfirmRecord helps here. That means I have to connect to it to check if its still valid? At least here it would stay for hours.

Comment: The problem still persists. The service does not want to disappear, it stays there until I want to connect to it. Is there any interval refresh I can fire with bonjour?